# ¿que pasa si detengo el servicio de publicacion de world wide web?

Tags: xampp

Estoy queriendo arreglar un error que me salto cuando instale el server XAMPP. No me deja arrancar apache y el error dice que el puerto esta usado por el proceso PID 4 puerto 80. Unas cuantas personas en foros dicen que debo de cambiar de automatico a manual el servicio de publicacion de world wide web y detenerlo...La verdad estoy en duda,¿que debo de hacer?.

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.